# Non US Citizen, non-resident, remote worker tax liability?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

So a friend of mind is not a US citizen, and Non-resident, he's working as a contractor remotely for a company in the US from his own country.

And he has an international bank account in one of the banks in the US. He receives his salary on this account.

I'm asking if he's required to pay any taxes in the US ?